# Primefaces Picketlist; add Item with JS

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

It is possible to add Items over the javascript wigdet option?

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{pickListView.features}" var="features" itemLabel="#{features}" itemValue="#{features}"
    showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" widgetVar="picklist" />
```

In JS I can use

```
Primefaces.widgets."widgetname".add();
```

to transfer the selected item to targetlist.

Is there a way with JS and Primefaces-Widget to add items to the sourcelist?

Comment: What do you mean by "add to the source list"? Do you mean transferring items from the target list back to the source list or updating the backing data structure for the list?

Comment: to update the backing data Structure with JS.

Comment: lookup `remoteCommand` in the Primefaces library

Comment: thank you kolossus. remoteCommand works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with

```
remoteCommand
```

[RemoteCommand - Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml)